# How to select an element by position when input is a variable in xquery?

Tags: variables, input, fetch, position, xquery

I have a variable called VariableInput and we are storing complete XML into this VariableInput. and the XML payload looks like below

```
<MaterialList>
        <Material>
            <Number>12345678</Number>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Phone>7000049851</Phone>
            <MID>123</MID>              
        </Material>
        <Material>
            <Number>1111111</Number>
            <Name>DEF</Name>
            <Phone>7000049852</Phone>
            <MID>345</MID>
                    </Material>             
<MaterialList>
```

Now I want to fetch Number 1111111 using this Vaeriable (VariableInput). Please help me here

I tried giving
$input.VariableInput/*:MaterialList/*:Material/*[position() = 2]
and
doc("$input.VariableInput")/MaterialList/Material/Number[2] but dint work

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how exactly the variable is bound, if you bind the element you need e.g.

```
let $xml := <MaterialList>
        <Material>
            <Number>12345678</Number>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Phone>7000049851</Phone>
            <MID>123</MID>              
        </Material>
        <Material>
            <Number>1111111</Number>
            <Name>DEF</Name>
            <Phone>7000049852</Phone>
            <MID>345</MID>
        </Material>             
    </MaterialList>
return $xml/Material[2]/Number
```

if you bind that XML as a document you need e.g.

```
let $xml := document { <MaterialList>
        <Material>
            <Number>12345678</Number>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Phone>7000049851</Phone>
            <MID>123</MID>              
        </Material>
        <Material>
            <Number>1111111</Number>
            <Name>DEF</Name>
            <Phone>7000049852</Phone>
            <MID>345</MID>
        </Material>             
    </MaterialList>
}
return $xml/MaterialList/Material[2]/Number
```

So you need to explain better in which environment and how there exactly you bind the variable and how it is typed.

Answer (score 1):

The path you want is `/MaterialList/Material[2]/Number`.

But I'm not sure what kind of variable `VariableInput` is, so I can't tell you how to use this expression in your wider code.